# Why my "mini" server network card freeze when transfering files?

Tags: linux, networking

i have a huge problem regarding my home mini server. 
The mini server configuration is:

- Via Epia C3 1GGHz with 1 GB RAM.
- 1 internal hard disk 70GB and 1 external USB hard disk 500 GB
- Operating system: Lubuntu 11.10

I bought this mini pc to have a mini server with low consumption (it consume 20-30 watt under work).
I've configured it with Samba and NFS share and I used it as print- and file server.

The problem is simple: when I copy files from the server to a client .. my server network card freezes! It stop to work... if i ping it, it not respond..after a while, it restart to work.

I have tried to change the network cable (with no result) then, for example, the MTU value of the mini server, from 1500 to 1480, 1460 and so on... It seems to work a little better, but after a while, it re-start again to not work.

I don't know really where is the problem and what try to change. 
Maybe I haveve to reinstall another Linux Distribution and retry to configure all ?

Any advice is appreciated!

EDIT: one important note: I havee changed the fan of the processor with another one less noisy. Maybe,Is the file transfer a CPU consumption (and heating) operation ?

EDIT 2: I've just used a "USB to LAN" dongle connected to a USB port. Now, my mini server don't REBOOT anymore and works properly with a low LAN speed. So the problem was on my LAN card but only when I copy/move files via Samba or NFS!

Comment: Run a console on this and monitor the CPU load during a transfer. If that goes to 100% there is your answer. If there is CPU to spare I wouldn't know what is causing it. P.S. Why NFS and Samba ? It is underpowered enough as it is so I would just run Samba. Any modern OS these days can use Samba in stead of NFS.

Comment: What make is the network card? Can you add a `lsmod` output to your question?

Comment: No Cpu, don't go to 100%. But after the first megabyte transfered (10-15 mb) it stop works.

Comment: Anything in the logs...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was an incompatibility with Lubuntu 11.10 and my Via Epia C3 1ghz M10000.
Installed Debian, and it works like a charm!